# Can't decode extremely simple JSON in python

Tags: python, json, decode

I keep getting 'JSON could not be decoded' when I run this extremely simple piece of code:

```
import json

dic = {'John':0}
test = open('testjson.json','w+')
json.dump(dic,test)
datos = json.load(test)
```

The file is written correctly as when I open it I can see the JSON just fine, problem is it won't load it in the variable named `datos`, any tips?

Answer (score 0):

You should seek back to the start of the file before reading it again:

```
test.seek(0)
datos = json.load(test)
```

Comment: Is the file being in write mode a problem?

Comment: That worked, thank you! Is there any way to avoid the positioning on the file? I mean is there any way I can just read the whole file without positioning myself on position 0?

Comment: @cricket_007 No, or only in as much as it's already been written to; so the current position is after the write (leaving nothing to read).

Comment: @Alejo You could close and open it again (have a look at context managers) - but why are you desperate not to seek?

Comment: @Alejo Not really, other option is to re-open the file again and read from it. Note that you should flush or close the file explicitly in that case, or better use with statement like Ollie mentioned. (Currently the read operation is taking care of flushing for you, but you should not rely on it).

Answer (score 0):

Why not just load the json from `dic`?

```
datos = json.dumps(dic)
```

You don't have to load it from file.